# Install bash function without user having to source a file

Tags: bash, shell, bash-functions

Is there a way to install a bash function into a user's environment without them having to source the file? Typically I see installations where the function is in a file and the end user has to source the file from ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile.

Say I have a bash function like so:

```
bunion(){
  "$@" | bxn
}

export -f bunion
```

which simply pipes their program into mine.  Is there some way to write that bash function to the bash hash or something?

Comment: Do you mean without having them source a _separate_ file? How would the function enter the user shell's environment if the code for it was not sourced? If you want the function to be available for _all_ users, modify a `bash`-related startup file under `/etc`.

Comment: sure, is there some /etc/bash.d whatever file/folder that gets loaded by default by bash? I was under the impression that each user had to actively source files pretty much anywhere outside of their $HOME dir

Comment: Read the "INVOCATION" section of the the `bash` manual to see what files under `/etc` are used by the shell (it may differ slightly between different systems). Look at those files to see what they are doing. Modify (or add) the appropriate file to enable your function.

Comment: Also note that your function is recursive (will call itself). I can't tell whether this is by design or by mistake.

Comment: I am not sure  why but I have seen bash functions call the `command` version of themselves, it's very bizarre, w/o explicitly putting command in front

Comment: Calling `command bunion` inside the function would make the shell call a non-function command called `bunion`, not the function called `bunion`.